# not able to manipulate pivot table in my laravel application

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

**new-job.blade.php**

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple categories  form-control" name="categories[]" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach($array['categories'] as $key => $category)
        <option value="{!! $category->id !!}">{!! $category->category_name !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This is the multiple select box and it is working. $array['categories'] have all the categories  in my category table

And in controller

```
dd($request['categories']);
```

gives me an an array of selected category id's eg: ['1','2']

but when i try to sync it with pivot table

```
$job->categories()->sync($request['categories']);
```

I'am getting this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`jobs_website`.`category_job_post`, CONSTRAINT
>   `category_job_post_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
>   REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `category_job_post` (`category_id`, `job_post_id`) values (11, 1))

I don't have an id like 11 in my category table

**JobPost.php**

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_job_post', 'category_id', 'job_post_id');
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function jobs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\JobPost');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the column names

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_job_post', 'job_post_id', 'category_id');
}
```